# CSS div positioning issue

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning

I have no clue how to build this simple layout.

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

... and this is what I have so far:

http://cssdesk.com/vQ3qr

How do I get the yellow div in the top right corner?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="gray-wrapper">
   <div class="red">centered</div>
   <div class="yellow">top right corner</div>
   <div class="aqua">100% width</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gray-wrapper{
width:500px;
height:200px;
background:gray;
border:4px solid gray;
}
.red{
width:200px;
height:100px;
margin:0 auto;
background:red;

}
.yellow{
width:50px;
height:100px;
float:right;
background:yellow;
}
.aqua{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the `yellow` div first in the html..

```
<div class="gray-wrapper">
   <div class="yellow">top right corner</div>
   <div class="red">centered</div>
   <div class="aqua">100% width</div>
</div>
```

Demo at http://cssdesk.com/KYRTT

Comment: @Ronnie: When you float a DIV, the browser positions it below the content it has built so far, then builds the content that follows the floated DIV in the HTML stream to "flow" around the floated DIV. So by moving the `yellow` DIV to the top, it goes to the top right corner.

Comment: Thanks jalynn - think I get it now. Am sure I would definitely get it if I played around with it for a while.

Comment: @Ronnie, see http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101 (*and particularly http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101#section5*).
The issue is that it floats right/left in relation to where it was supposed to be before you float it.. So since the previous element is a block, the *normal* flow dictated that it starts below it. then it applies the float, and it goes to the right.. Same thing would happen if you floated it left.. (*but because visually left is first in our culture, you put it first in the html and never experience the problem..*)

Answer (score 1):

```
body{background:white}


.gray-wrapper{
 width:500px;
height:200px;
background:gray;
border:4px solid gray;
}


.red{
width:200px;
height:100px;
margin-left: 150px;
background:red;
 float:left; 



}


.yellow{
width:50px;
height:100px;
float:right;
background:yellow;
}


.aqua{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:aqua;
float: left;
}
```

DONE!